# What is the most efficient way to max-pool a 2d matrix and get the index of the max-item too?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I found the below answer on implementing max-pooling with 'numpy' and 'block_reduce' of skimage. But it doesn't show how to get the index of the max value (preferably with respect to the actual matrix, not the pooled one). What is the most computationally fast solution to this?

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.measure

a = np.array([
      [  20,  200,   -5,   23],
      [ -13,  134,  119,  100],
      [ 120,   32,   49,   25],
      [-120,   12,    9,   23]
])
skimage.measure.block_reduce(a, (2,2), np.max)
```

Comment: `np.argmax` does the trick.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Getting error,
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer